# How to keep track of SwiftUI Alternate Icons?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

First off, I'm very new to Swift and SwiftUI, so this probably has some obvious answer. I have a view for selecting alternate app icons, but I want to have a checkmark next to the selected icon for the user to be able to know what icon they currently have selected. I can't seem to figure out how to do this though, and seem to be missing something here.

[This is what I want it to look like but have it change based off of when the user selects each icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWuPi.jpg) I have it so that the icon already changes but I can't figure out how to get it so that it dynamically changes the checkmark.

Here is the code for my view with the list of app icons.

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct AppIconSettingsView: View {

    //MARK: -Properties
    
    func changeIcon(iconName: String) {
        if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons {
            UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(iconName){ error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Done!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkselected(nameofselected: String){
        if nameofselected == isSelected {
          
        }
    }
    
    @State var isSelected: String = "Default"
    
    //MARK: -Body
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                    //set icon
                UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(nil)
                
                isSelected = "Default"
            }) {
                
    //USE 60x60 ICON FOR PREVIEW
                
                AppIconRowSettingsView(appicon: "DefaultAppIconPreview", appiconname: "Default", selected: true)
            } //end of button
          
            Button(action: {
                    changeIcon(iconName: "DarkIcon")
                
                isSelected = "Dark"
            }) {
                
                AppIconRowSettingsView(appicon: "DarkAppIconPreview", appiconname: "Dark", selected: false)
            } //end of button
        }
        
    }
        
}
```

And then here is the code for the rows:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AppIconRowSettingsView: View {
    
    //MARK: -Properties
    
    var appicon: String
    var appiconname: String
    var selected: Bool

    //MARK: -Body
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image(appicon)

                .cornerRadius(15.0)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(.vertical, 7.0)
            
            Text(appiconname)
                .font(.title2)
                .padding(.leading, 15.0)

            Spacer()
            
            if selected == true{
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
              
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to use SwiftUI's [transition animation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+%22transition+animation%22) for a dynamic animation.

Comment: Within AppIconRowSettingsView, you need to use Binding to connect the selected: Bool to the @State isSelected in the parent view.  When you pass "selected: true" into the initializer, it sets the value forever. Instead you should pass "selected: $isSelected". I'd also recommend changing isSelected from a String to a custom enum or Bool.